# Which sentence structure is correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

1. Alle Schüler müssen sich nach dem Sportunterricht duschen.
2. Alle Schüler müssen nach dem Sportunterricht sich duschen.

Which one is the correct sentence structure?

Answer (score 5):

When using reflexive verbs together with a modal verb, the reflexive pronoun sticks to the modal, because the modal is the finite verb.

> Alle Schüler **müssen sich** nach dem Sportunterricht duschen.
>
> Du **kannst dich** ab morgen um einen Platz bewerben.
>
> Er **will sich** nicht den Magen verderben.

Answer (score 0):

If an object is a pronoun, it is usually placed close to the finite verb (here: "müssen").

Therefore 1. is correct.

This is not limited to the reflexive pronoun. For example:

> Ich muss mich nach dem Sportunterricht waschen.

If the object is not a pronoun its position can be chosen more freely:

> Ich muss meine Hände nach der Arbeit waschen.
>
> Ich muss nach der Arbeit meine Hände waschen.

are both correct.

If both the dative object and the accusative object are pronouns, the accusative is generally placed before the dative:

> Meine Hände sind schmutzig. Ich muss sie mir waschen.